# Fedora 20. Authentication requires a different password from su

Tags: password, authentication

In Fedora 20 (using Mate desktop) I have tried to change the default keyboard layout from US English to UK English, but am asked for "Authentication". The password I have for `su` is not accepted, and I do not recall having set a different one anywhere. Please, why does this happen, and how to I get round it?

This may be two questions: How to authenticate? and How to set the default keyboard layout? I hope this is acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried your own password?

Comment: `su` requires the password for the target account, `root` by default. Have you tried using `sudo`, which requires your password?